# Unable to save form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to save a form, and I am so lost on why it refuses to save. Does anybod have a clue what might be wrong?

Here's the form code:

```
  <%= form_for @service, url: services_path do |f| %> 
  <% @profiles.each do |profile| %>
      <%= f.text_field :service_id,  value: "#{profile.service_id}" %>

      <div class="media">
        <a class="media-left" href="#">
          <%= image_tag profile.avatar, height: '45', width: '45', class: 'img-circle' %>
        </a>
        <div class="media-body">
          <h4 class="media-heading"><%= profile.service_username %></h4>
            <%= profile.service %>
        </div>
      </div>

    <% end %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

and

```
@service = current_user.services.new
```

the association between them are:

```
user has_many :services
service belongs_to :user
```

and the services controller create looks like this:

```
def create
@service = current_user.services.new(service_params)
if @service.save
  flash[:notice] = "success"
  redirect_to root_url
else
  flash[:alert] = "Unable to add"
  redirect_to :back
end
end
```

my logs say:

```
Started POST "/services" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-01-17 18:09:44 -0800
Processing by ServicesController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",  "authenticity_token"=>"lsW5aVuVUCQrHsaCo+uxbR11sF3mph3lTnM8O/Dtxn8=", "service"=> {"service_id"=>"2967861508"}, "commit"=>"Create Service"}
User Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 30       ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
(0.2ms)  BEGIN
(0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/schedules
Completed 302 Found in 9ms (ActiveRecord: 1.1ms)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops, minor edit below (@service.errors instead of @validation.errors):

From your logs, you can see that you got into the controller create method and the save failed. This is usually a validation problem but I can't tell from what you posted. I would put @service.errors into the flash instead of just "unable to add". This should help you and future users see what's going on when the create fails.

Comment: Thanks, as an edit to yours I think @service.errors.full_messages is what you meant. When I did that I was successful in finding the error. Thanks :)!